# integrate data between oracle and sql server

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2012

I have an oracle database that is very large in size.

I also have a sql server database. I want to integrate data from the oracle database to the sql server database and also the opposite way. This does not need to be real time but can work in the background possibly on defined intervals during the day.

What is the process for setting this up and how may it be achieved?

Comment: Witch operating system are u using? are the both db on the same system?

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate"? Do you want Oracle to have a read-only copy of the Sql Server data and vice versa?  Do you want to sync back and forth?  Why can't the applications that are accessing this data be modified to deal with the data in their respective locations?

Answer (score 2):

You should look into Microsoft SSIS:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use Oracle Golden Gate software.  It does cost money but it supports real time data movement between many different database architectures, including the ones you specifically care about.

Comment: Totally unnecessary additional software to perform functionality that is already native to both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Creating DB links is the best option for this.  With DB links the databases can talk to each other directly.  No need for additional software or programming, this is standard functionality in Oracle and SQL Server and is very reliable.